# trouble while moving certificates into new computer

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4.3, code-signing, organizer

I'm moving computer to develop on a new one, SO ! I'm trying to build application in the new one with the certificates of the older one !

I exported all from keychain, and I made the download of the files automatically (by clicking on the refresh button) on the Organizer. So here is the problem : I cannot archive any applications (1 have one application publicated into 2 differents applications on the store):

[Library Organiser](http://hpics.li/6075e1a) 
[Teams Organizer](http://hpics.li/01e72fa)
[Teams Organizer](http://hpics.li/f943769)
[Code Signin in XCODE](http://hpics.li/57b10e3)
[Error screen](http://hpics.li/5d44b69)

I really don't understand my mistake !

I deleted all the certificates in the new machine, and after I make this video to explain how I made . There is a mistake on it, but I don't know when and where : [VIDEO](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E18cxSOfWJ4&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: You exported all means that thing includes taking Private key(.p12) of old computer to new one's keychain? And If yes then second most improtant thing to do is to Download Certificates(developer.cer and distribution.cer) from provisionaing profile and install them to new mac's keychain. You did this too?

Comment: I'va exported the .p12 files from the old computer. I don't remember to install the developper certificate so I went to the portal and install it. I got the same error message !

Comment: @Dhaval : Please check my video in the initial post, I delete all and re-make all my operations.... Thanks in advance

Comment: @Dhaval : I had missed to re-import the public. I had trouble so I used the CLI and renamed it in kechains but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that your old Mac is the one by which you created CSR and Development and Distribution certificates.

Follow this simple steps:-

1. First open keychain in old mac and Export the private key as p12
2. Then use this .p12 file in new mac by just double clicking on it and give the password what you given.
3. Log in to provisioning portal and select Certificates Download both ios_developement.cer and ios_distribution.cer in new Mac. Double click on those two certificates if it successfully added to new mac's keychain then you are good to go with all the provisioning profiles associated to those certificates (You can see the associated provisioning profiles list of particular certificate in certificate section.)
4. Download provisioning profiles from portal and double click to add it to xcode.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not saved your private keys, you have to revoke your certificates and create new ones. Else: as @Dhaval wrote: you have to export your saved keys to your keychain and your certificates will work.

Comment: thanks. I can archive applications in the old mac so I export all certificates and pulic an privates keys and import it in the new one, Do I have to download files from the IOS DEV portal?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is to go into the Organizer NOT the keychain.

Select Developer profile of the left. 
At the bottom of the window click export : it'll create an archive with ALL you need you can import on another xcode seat.